# Copying dynamic range of cells from inactive workbook to pasting to active workbook at pointed places

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to vba and with the help of stackoverflow guidance, i am learning. 
I am trying to copy four different ranges of cells (dynamic in nature, but all have same row numbers, but different columns) (the source book shall be open and the user to select the range in particular order) so that the same can be pasted to target workbook in the same order.
I could not attach the sample source workbook (the name in future will change) and target workbooks as i am newbie here.
source book contains various col like, slno, acct no, name, amt, ifsc, remarks, arrears etc and the no of rows may be changing.
target book contains, only four colums, like, amt,acct no, name and ifsc in the same order.

From the source book, i need, acct, ifsc, name and amt col data to be pasted in target workbook, viz, amt, acct no, name and ifsc.

i tried the following code using this forum...

but, it copies only col a to g and not dynamic. I wish, it could ask some user input for all four ranges.

thanks..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim excel As excel.Application
    Dim wb As excel.Workbook
    Dim sht As excel.Worksheet
    Dim f As Object

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    f.Show

    Set excel = CreateObject("excel.Application")
    Set wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(f.SelectedItems(1))
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    sht.Activate

    sht.Columns("A:G").Copy
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working you can delete the unwanted columns by adding this code between `Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` and `wb.close`.

```
    Dim cel As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        For Each cel In Intersect(.UsedRange, .[1:1])
            If cel.Value2 = "" Or InStr(1, "amtacct nonameifsc", cel.Value2) = 0 Then
                cel.EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
```